# Changing the focus of the window on Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

Writing some tests I had to click on a link that leads to another tab then I needed to click on another link, that last step isn't working (Unable to find link "Example" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)).
Should I need to change focus to the new tab first? How do I do that?

Comment: Hello! I would write a another test starting from this new tab opened. I use a lot capybara but i never found me in this situation. Tip: best practice is always write a short test

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are treated as new windows in Capybara, so you need to move to the new window using Capybaras window api. It will look something like

```
new_window = window_opened_by do
  # here you are in the context of the original window but your actions are expected to open a new tab/window
  click_link 'the link that opens the new tab'
end

within_window(new_window) do
  # this is in the context of the newly opened tab/window
  click_link 'the link inside the new tab'
end

# here you will be back in the context of the first window

new_window.close # if you want to close the tab that was opened
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add `switch_to_window(windows.last)` before the action